# Reference current object (onclick for div) in a seperate function call

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am designing a simple tic-tac-toe game and have run into a bit of a problem.
I've used a grid of div's to act as the games tiles, each with their own 'onclick' property.

I would like to call several functions when a tile is clicked and have defined a function, main(), to handle this; however as you will see below, one of my functions- **placeUserTile(el)**, relies on a reference to the current object. In this case, the div which has been selected.

How can I reference the **el** in **placeUserTile(el)** from the **main()** function?

index.html

```
    <!-- Need to call main() func with current object reference 
         passed in to my placeUserTile() function -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile" id="r1c1" onclick="main(this)"></div>
```

master.js

```
    function placeUserTile(el){
    var tileIsEmpty  = true;
    // If the selected tile has at least one child,
    // do not allow placement of another tile.
    if (el.firstChild) {
     tileIsEmpty = false;
    }
    if(tileIsEmpty === true){
     cloneUserIcon();
    }
    el.appendChild(newUserIcon);
    newUserIcon.style.display = null;
    }

    function main(){
    evaluateTurn();
    placeUserTile(el);
    }
```

Comment: Is this a question about scoping? have a look at this: https://jsbin.com/qupovunexe/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Please don't post the answer in the question. You could write the solution in the answer section and can give a tick to yourself. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
function placeUserTile(el){
   var tileIsEmpty  = true;
   // If the selected tile has at least one child,
   // do not allow placement of another tile.
   if (el.firstChild) {
      tileIsEmpty = false;
   }
   if(tileIsEmpty === true){
      cloneUserIcon();
   }
   el.appendChild(newUserIcon);
   newUserIcon.style.display = null;
}

function main(targetElement){
   evaluateTurn();
   placeUserTile(targetElement);
}
```

Comment: Tested this out. This also works. Thanks so much!! :)